# Write a condition to execute 2 switch-case functions?

Tags: atmega328, switch

I'm new to programming and using Arduino products, and was wondering if someone wouldn't mind assisting me with a project I'm trying to tackle?

If you review my code below, I have 3 conditions within my "idle" case, and the program is constantly looking for any of those 3 conditions. If the first condition is met, then case 1 is called; if the second condition is met, then case 2 is called; if the third condition is met, then case 3 is called. All 3 cases return to the "idle" case once done running.

What I would like to do is find some way to insert the "warning" case if any of the conditions are met, BEFORE going to case 1, case 2 or case 3, without writing the functions of the "warning" case over each time for each of the other 3 cases. Essentially, the flow would be like this:

condition 1 --> warning --> case 1 --> case idle;

condition 2 --> warning --> case 2 --> case idle;

condition 3 --> warning --> case 3 --> case idle:

```cpp
void loop() {
  static byte theState = idle;
  switch (theState)
  {
    case idle:
      if (voltageA0 > 1.0) {
        theState = case1;
      }

      if (voltageA1 < 2.0) {
        theState = case2;
      }

      if (voltageA2 > 3.5) {
        theState = case3;
      }
      break;
    case warning:
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      delay(0);
      break;
    case 1:
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      delay(0);
      theState = idle;
      break;
    case 2:
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      delay(0);
      theState = idle;
      break;
    case 3:
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
      delay(0);
      theState = idle;
      break;
  }
}
```

Also, if there is a more efficient way to do this, code-wise, I'm all ears!

Comment: Simplifying the code before posting it is generally a good thing. But if you change it so much that it becomes mostly unrelated to the original one, then a proper answer to the question may not be applicable to your real problem. Judging from your comments to Look Alterno's answer, this is exactly what happened. The _blocking_ code you posted is a very different beast from the non blocking one you are using. Please, edit the question to make it relevant to your actual problem. This would be more useful than trying to explain in comments the extent to which the codes differ.

Answer (score 1):

There is something incoherent in your code. It is structured as a finite
state machine, and yet you are using `delay()` within it. In this kind of
scenario, the whole purpose of a state machine is to avoid using
`delay()`, so that your program never blocks. If your program happens to
not have anything better to do than delaying, then you can forgo the
state machine and write much simpler code. For example:

```c++
void warn_and_flash(byte pin)
{
    // Flash the "warning" LED.
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);

    // Flash the requested LED.
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
    if (voltageA0 > 1.0) warn_and_flash(8);
    if (voltageA1 < 2.0) warn_and_flash(9);
    if (voltageA2 > 3.5) warn_and_flash(10);
}
```

Comment: I agree. Imagine you are writing code for a motor car, and the driver puts on the left indicator, which is supposed to flash once every second. Do you **really** want to the car to ignore the other inputs (brakes, accelerator, air conditioning) for an entire second while you `delay` for one second? I think not.

Answer (score 0):

```
case idle:
  if (voltageA0 > 1.0 || voltageA1 < 2.0 || voltageA2 > 3.5) {
     digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(7, LOW);
     delay(0);     

     if (voltageA0 > 1.0) {
        theState = case1;
        }

    if (voltageA1 < 2.0) {
       theState = case2;
       }

    if (voltageA2 > 3.5) {
       theState = case3;
       }
   }
```

EDIT:
To clarify original answer, I inlined the "warning" code and deleted the "case warning", as obviously this state is not longer needed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance guys! I suppose I should have explained why I'm using a state machine for the code. The code I gave the example of omits the millis() functions that I actually have in my real code. I re-wrote the example without the millis() functions to simply what I'm trying to do, but cases "warning", "1", "2", and "3" all use millis() functions to trigger LEDs and relays. Sorry for not explaining that.

Edgar, thanks for pointing out the "delay(0);" redundancy I had... I was thinking that may have been redundant, but wasn't sure. Based on the fact that I need to...

Comment: ...call a different set of functions after the "warning" function, specific to the condition that was met, I don't believe the example you suggested would work. I may be wrong though so please let me know if I missed something :)

Look Alterno, thank you for your help as well. Something else I didn't explain is that the "warning" state/function also remedies the conditions by triggering relays to cut voltage to some devices. The successive cases (1, 2, 3) are just used as an indicator to tell me which condition was just met, after the warning state remedies the problem.

Comment: So think of it this way... 

condition 1 will trigger the warning case, then go to case 1, where an LED will flash 5 times to indicate condition 1 was just met

condition 2 will trigger the warning case, then go to case 2, where an LED will flash 10 times to indicate condition 2 was just met

condition 3 will trigger the warning case, then go to case 3, where an LED will flash 10 times to indicate condition 3 was just met

Again, my fault for not elaborating all of this initially. Does this make more sense?? Thanks again, very much, for the help!

Comment: @Andrew. That's what the code does: if **any** condition is met, then `warning` is executed. After that, the code tests for the specific condition (case 1, 2 or 3) and executed the pertinent action(s).

Comment: thanks! But yeah the warning state will remedy any of the 3 conditions, so checking for the condition AFTER the warning state won't do any good unfortunately. The best way to think of it is let's say voltage on pin A0 increases as a pot of water gets hotter. Once the pot of water reaches a certain temperature (voltage), the "warning" function illuminates an LED for, let's say 10 minutes, while also cutting the heat source to the pot of water. Once that 10 mins is up, the condition-related case (1, 2, or 3) will flash an LED a certain number of times to indicate which cond was met

Comment: If the water temperature drops below a certain temperature/voltage, then the warning case is triggered, and then case 2 is triggered to flash an LED a different number of times to indicate that condition 2 was triggered. These are not the most sensible examples, but it is easier to explain it that way than what and how I'm truly monitor the inputs on the Analog pins. Hope that makes more sense and thanks again!! :)

Comment: @Andrew. See the edited code for better explanation.